# Decrypt code , from ruby to js

Tags: javascript, ruby, encryption, crypt

does anyone know how to translate below ruby script to javascript?

```
source = ENCRYPTED_STRING
cipher = OpenSSL::Cipher::Cipher.new('AES-128-ECB')
cipher.decrypt
cipher.key = ['SECRET'].pack('H*')
decoded = Base64.decode64(source)
decrypted = cipher.update(decoded) + cipher.final
```

Comment: Find a library that does the AES encryption. That would be the start and follow its directions.

Comment: Google is your friend.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you want to encrypt a string using "SECRET" as a passphrase.

Here's an example using [crypto-js](https://code.google.com/p/crypto-js/#AES):

```
source = ENCRYPTED_STRING
var encrypted = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(source, "SECRET");
```

Answer (score 0):

http://yijiebuyi.com/blog/13e2ae33082ac12ba4946b033be04bb5.html

problem solved.

    `function decryption(data, key) {
        var iv = "";
        var clearEncoding = 'utf8';
        var cipherEncoding = 'base64';
        var cipherChunks = [];
        var decipher = crypto.createDecipheriv('aes-128-ecb', key, iv);
        decipher.setAutoPadding(true);
        cipherChunks.push(decipher.update(data, cipherEncoding, clearEncoding));
        cipherChunks.push(decipher.final(clearEncoding));
        return cipherChunks.join('');
    }`